# INSERT INTO T-SQL statement

Tags: t-sql

Question: State what is wrong with the following T-SQL.

```
INSERT INTO dbo.[Pricing_ProductPrice]
(DealerPrice,PricingRegion,ProductId,RetailPrice)
VALUE
('70.00','635727362389933863','ZQ','99621-05V','120.00','A')
```

My Answer:

I don't know if there are any more but this is what I have so far:

- USE statement is missing to use which database
- GO statement is    missing
- Pricing_Product Price table is around square brackets. No    brackets
  needed.
- Should be VALUES, not VALUE
- More values than    columns.  6 values going into 4 columns.

Are there any more issues I am missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You also have to ensure that you are inserting correct types into your columns. For example, ProductId, I assume it is an INT or something like this so 'ZQ' won't work.